# Visual Studio 2008, excel add-in hangs when stepping in debugger

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, vsto, excel-2010

I have a background worker in my C# vsto excel add-in that reads data from an excel sheet. Recently, and for no apparent reason, Visual Studio hasn't been stepping through the background worker code correctly.

I have Visual Studio set to break on all exceptions. Previously, when an exception occurred or I hit a breakpoint, Visual Studio would break and I could step (<kbd>F10</kbd>)  through my code, as normal. Now however, when Visual Studio breaks I can sometimes step once or twice, but then the background worker/excel will suddenly hang (Sometimes Visual Studio hangs too). If I pause execution and look at threads, I can see that none of them are in my code anymore.

I've tried [this](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB957912) hotfix, but it hasn't helped.

Has anyone encountered this before?

**Additional Info**: I've used git to roll back to a version from before I was experiencing this issue, and it is now present in that version as well. This leads me to suspect it's something specific to visual studio.

Comment: what changed in your set up?

Comment: @K_B: Nothing, as far as I'm aware. I may have added and removed a reference. Since this has started happening I've been playing with my build settings, but nothing I've tried so far has had an effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The solution, from MSDN's Amanda Zhu](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/a9d02d7d-8edd-4f0e-985d-2e4994bc36c7/#8a663ca3-ca29-4d8c-ba67-86365ae27a68), was to restore Visual Studio's default settings.

> Navigate to  \Common7\IDE (default is C:\Program Files \Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE);

and run:

> Devenv.exe /ResetSettings: Restores the IDE's default settings, optionally resets to the specified VSSettings file.